# Version conflict while adding Google Cloud Storage support to existing Webapp

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a webapp & a java application that connects to Bigquery. I'm trying to add support for Cloud Storage using the StorageSample example.

But when running this code:

```
Storage storage = new Storage.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
    BigqueryUtils.PROJECT_ID).build();
```

I get the following error:

```
You are currently running with version 1.17.0-rc of google-api-client. You need version 1.14.1-beta of google-api-client to run version 1.14.1-beta of the Cloud Storage API library.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix: Hi Febian: Why don't you just grab a new version of the client lib from [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/storage/v1beta2)?
Better way to manage libs: I have had best luck using Maven to manage dependencies for Google Java Client Libs. Check out the "Add Library to Your Project" link on the same page.